# Where should I add "with app.app context" to an API to create a link with a database?

Tags: python, flask

I am new to Python and trying to create an Flask API that will be linked to my database.

When I try to run the code, I have the following error :

> RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
>
> This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
> to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
> this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
> documentation for more information.

I therefore tried to look into:

`with app.app_context(): cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()`

But it still doesn't work, I am wondering if I am adding it in the "wrong place" ?

Should I try another way of fixing the issue ?

Here is the code I tried:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse, abort
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
app = Flask("heart_diseases_api")
api = Api(app)
# #MySQL configurations
mysql = MySQL()
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = '****'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'heart_diseases_tables
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'``mysql.init_app(app)
conn = mysql.connect()
cursor =conn.cursor()
class CreatePerson(Resource):
    def post(self):
        with app.app_context():
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    try:
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('age', required = True)
        parser.add_argument('blood_pressure', required = True)
        parser.add_argument('bmi', required = True)
        parser.add_argument('cholcheck', required = True)
```

etc....